# UDP chat on android

Tags: android, service, udp, blocking, android-anr-dialog

I have a school assignment about building a UDP based chat client on android. Now, my first idea was to make an activity that starts a service and the service handle all the networking and the activity all the input an output. But a have found a problem.

If i try to start the service so that the startCommand function starts and calls the socket.receive to start receiving network message, I can not bind the service so that i can pass input from the activity to the service (input = messages that the user want to send). It just hangs and a ANR exception is thrown. If i only bind it (so that receive is never called), it works like a Charm.

Maybe I'm not approaching this problem right. Or should it work to bind the service wen it's on a blocking receive call?

Comment: Without seeing the code it's hard to diagnose. My first guess would be that you run your network functionality in the thread of the service (which is the main UI thread). This blocks it and you get an ANR. You should always run network calls within a seperate thread.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this once. I took the necessary data needed to track down the other device and fed it into an asyncTask where I kicked off a Runnable that basically kept a connection going on in the background.(This way you don't have to worry about binding) I found that instead of making your own socket connections its easier just to use Apache [Mina](http://mina.apache.org/) or [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty). (No need to reinvent the wheel). If you just pass the data transmissions from the session running in the background to a List or a Queue and have an asyncTask check it and update the UI accordingly you should be all set for chatting. Maybe this isn't the best way, but it worked for me. Hope some of this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the whole point of the assignment is to reinvent the wheel... so I need to get it to work with basic UDP.

Comment: That is fine it sounds like you have your sockets working outside of the android os. So like alextsc was implying I think your confused with the way a services works. Services are not the same as threads. Even though you bind a service you still need to create a separate thread for your receiver, and call a new thread for message you send. So you could have at anyone time three threads running the sender, receiver, and Activity running on the UI.